# how to get simple URL in FB page

Tags: facebook, url, search-engine

When we create a page we get URL like this 
http://www.facebook.com/pages/Waqar-Attari-com/124695477593246

While i notice some other pages are simple link like
http://www.facebook.com/NokiaIndia

How can i change my page URL to 
http://www.facebook.com/pages/Waqar-Attari-com

Answer (score 6):

you can do it here:

http://www.facebook.com/username/

for a Facebook Page, you'll need 25 likes before you can do this... [fb-topic here](http://www.facebook.com/topic.php?uid=10381469571&topic=6826)